# Ideal system requirements for Magento 2 Development

Tags: magento2

What are the ideal or second-best system requirements for work/development in Magento 2.3/4?

Would be nice if you share your system stats the system with which you are working.
(i.e `ubuntu os 6gb ram` etc)

You can also add as an answer or comment your system stats the system with which you are working. (i.e `ubuntu os 6gb ram` etc) that would be definitely helpful to set up a system to work with Magento.

I mean operating system, ram, etc.

Comment: Happy that Magento SE Tweeted this question from their account
https://twitter.com/StackMagento/status/1431179700827828225

Comment: Can also add as answer or comment your system stats the system which you are working with. (i.e ubuntu os 6gb ram etc) that would be definately helpful to setup a system to work with magento

Answer (score 3):

The basic system requirement for Magento 2.4 are

1. Webserver - Apache 2.4 or Nginx 1.8
2. PHP 7.4
3. MySQL 8.0 (5.7 also supports)
4. Composer 1 is enough
5. Elasticsearch 7.6

please refer to the below link for further details
[System requirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html)

Both for developing and Production preferable is **Ubuntu OS** with minimum **8GB ram** needed for fast developing and lack free site.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, could you also please share your system stats ?

Comment: Would be nice if you share your system stats the system which you are working with. (i.e ubuntu os 6gb ram etc)

Comment: Processor - Intel® Core™ i7-10700 CPU @ 2.90GHz × 16 , OS - Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, Ram - 16 GB, 250 GB SSD hard dis, Graphics - Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CML GT2).

Comment: are these laptop configurations ?

Comment: Sorry I prefer desktop rather than laptop, these are the configurations I mentioned are my desktop.